# Angular Material switch between show and hide programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Is it possible to switch between the attributes show and hide by button click (programmatically)? I have for example a card with a map and a list view.
These are usually displayed side by side. On mobile devices, but is for the List view `flex = 100` increases. The map is no longer displayed. The user should however have the possibility to switch between the two views. How I can do that?

My example tags:

```
<md-card flex-gt-xs="40" flex-xs="100">
 <list></list>
</md-card>

<md-button>toggle Views</md-button>

<md-card flex="60" hide-xs show-gt-xs >
  <leaflet height="40vh" ></leaflet>
</md-card>
```

**Update:**

Summary

I would like to have 2 columns that can be switched on mobile devices, and side by side on larger devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.  `$mdMedia` does all the magic.

js:

```
 $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $mdMedia('sm');
        }, function (big) {
            $scope.screenIsSmall = $mdMedia('sm');
        });
```

View:

```
   <md-card flex="60" ng-hide="screenIsSmall&&!showMap" style="max-height: 40vh">
       <md-button ng-show="screenIsSmall" ng-click="showMap = !showMap">toggle</md-button>
       <leaflet height="40vh"></leaflet>
    </md-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/jAaAdV) demonstrates the basics of toggling programatically.

`md-button` has an `ng-click` attribute that calls the function `toggle()` which toggles the `view` value. `view` is passed to the `ng-if` of each card.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" style="height:100%" layout="column">
  <md-card flex-gt-xs="40" flex-xs="100" ng-if="view">
    Card 1
   <list></list>
  </md-card>

  <md-button ng-click="toggle()">toggle Views</md-button>

  <md-card flex="60" hide-xs show-gt-xs  ng-if="!view">
    Card2
    <leaflet height="40vh" ></leaflet>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache', 'ngDialog'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.view = true;
  $scope.toggle = function () {
    $scope.view = !$scope.view;
  }
});
```

You can replace `ng-if` with `ng-show` if you need to retain information in elements that you are toggling as `ng-if` recreates the element each time it is true.

Comment: the code only works if I'm not in the mobile view of the app.

Comment: @laren0815 I understand a bit more now after your update.

Answer (score 0):

app.component.html

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-sm="row wrap">
       <div fxFlex="50" class="flex-p">
              <mat-slide-toggle
                [checked]="isSlideChecked"
                (change)="toggleChanges($event)"
                >Hide/Show - card</mat-slide-toggle
              >
       </div>
</div>
```

```
<mat-card *ngIf="isSlideChecked">Simple card</mat-card>
```

app.component.ts

```
 isSlideChecked: boolean = false;

  toggleChanges($event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.isSlideChecked = $event.checked;
  }
```